# Не работает условие IF при проверке типа данных

Tags: python

На начальной стадии изучения Python, никак не могу понять почему не срабатывает условие?

```
print('Введите цифры: ')
a = input()
if (type(a) == int):
    print('Вы ввели цифры: ', a)
else:
    print('Вы ввели не цифры, а другие символы!')
```

Так же пробовал второй вариант кода. Все равно ничего не получается...

```
print('Введите цифры: ')
a = input()
if isinstance(a, int):
    print('Вы ввели цифры: ', a)
else:
    print('Вы ввели не цифры, а другие символы!')
```

Если в 2й строке пишу a =  int(input()), то выдает ошибку File "C:/PYTHON/Studies/lesson2.py", line 2, in 
a = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'gj'

Comment: Потому что `input()` возвращает строку.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = input()
if (type(a) == int):
```

`input` всегда возвращает строку, поэтому не может быть числом

нужно сделать такой код для вышей цели

```
try:
    value = int(input())
    print(f'Вы ввели цифры: {value}')
except ValueError:
    print('Вы ввели не цифры, а другие символы!')
```

так же можно использовать такой вариант:

```
value = input()

if value.isnumeric():
    print(f'Вы ввели цифры: {value}')
else:
    print('Вы ввели не цифры, а другие символы!')
```

Comment: Ваши примеры работают. Спасибо, буду разбираться...

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверить ещё вот так:

```
print('Введите цифры: ')
a = input()
if a.isdigit():
    print('Вы ввели цифры: ', a)
else:
    print('Вы ввели не цифры, а другие символы!')
```

`input` возвращает строку, но у строк есть методы проверки, в том числе, что строка состоит из цифр, что я и проверяю в этом коде.

Comment: Ваш способ так же работает. Спасибо за помощь. Возьму на вооружение.